# how to override zoom meeting voice when working with sdk in react and node js

Tags: sdk, webhooks, zoom-sdk

Hi I want to integrate language translator for zoom meeting sdk but I don't know how will I override the voice with my voice

I just want to get to know that how will i override the zoom meeting voice with my custom voice. i have to add multiple language translator

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.